# WPF Controls - Should code behind be avoided at all costs?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I have a WPF project and need to create a control that is specific to the domain but will be reused in multiple views.

The control must display a decimal value in 3 parts, the integral part and the decimal part split into 2 with different font sizes. I have a dependency property for the Amount and then split the amount in 3 parts in the code behind so I can show them in the specific labels. I also use the decimal amount to decide whether the amount is going up or down and subsequently change the background color of the control. All of this is done in the code behind. I know that some say that code behind is evil and I agree in most cases. However how would you implement this otherwise?

Comment: 'the decimal part split into 2 with different font sizes' - could you explain this a little further?

Comment: It's a detail and doesn't really make a difference to the question. Imagine I need to display the first 3 decimal points in front 10 and the rest in font 8.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it should not be avoided at **all costs**.

Remember, **Data is Data, UI is UI**.

For example, if you have code which does **only** UI stuff, then there is nothing wrong with having code behind.

Anything that works with actual data, including working with the `ViewModel` should generally be avoided in code-behind, as you would then be creating dependencies, which *breaks* the MVVM design pattern.

So to answer your question more directly, there isn't anything wrong with what you have done.

**EDIT**

Let me explain further.

Picture the scene, you have a View, with a button that needs to start a `Storyboard` when it has been clicked. (Of course, you can do this in XAML only, but this is just an example)

In this case, there is nothing wrong with adding a click event to the button and starting the storyboard from code-behind. This is **UI only** code, so it's safe.

However, let's say your button needs to change a property in your **ViewModel** when it is clicked. You **should not** get hold of the `DataContext` in the code-behind. You will need to use a `Command` because you need to keep the **View** separated from the **ViewModel**.

There's a stigma that if your views have code-behind, then you should be taken out back and shot in the back of the head, execution style. This is untrue.

All that said, MVVM is a **pattern**, not the law.

Comment: Agreed. I only reserve executions for those that choose to  use Windows Forms when they could prefer WPF.

Comment: I agree with this philosophy 100%. However some claim that all that can be done with code behind can be done in XAML (like your story board example). Is there some XAML construct that can help do the above?

Comment: @Klaws86 Not *everything* has a XAML only solution, and I'm pretty confident in saying that what you require has no XAML only solution. The code-behind is there for a reason, whilst XAML only feels unbelievably pro, sometimes it just isn't possible to achieve it, and **that isn't a bad thing**. Helping you create a control which does what you require is beyond the scope of your question, it would be a better idea to ask a new question if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting Amount in 3 in Code Behind, You can keep one Property Amount in ViewModel and Use a Converter with 3 Parameters to extract one of the three pieces of information for Display. So you can have 3 bindings like this:

```
"{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource AmountSplitterConverter},ConverterParameter=Integral}"

"{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource AmountSplitterConverter},ConverterParameter=Decimal1}"

"{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource AmountSplitterConverter},ConverterParameter=Decimal2}"
```

Let me know if you need any further help in implementing it or if it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately I need the Amount value and the previous value for it to be able to do the font logic on the control so this will only solve half the problem.