# WPF MVVM for complex application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm in the design phase of a WPF application with complex requirements:
I have to control the view by code because I have to enable, disable or hide elements depending on the user permission. Additionally in a TreeView I have to control the ContextMenu of the TreeViewItems depending of the Item-Type (internal logic) and the dependency of the user permission.
The Data to display are loade by stored procedures to datasets (multiple tables).
What's the experience with MVVM and maintenance (code complexity of MVVM compared with direct code behind) and all the stearing of controls visibility.

Automatic testing is not needed because the visible part must be included in the testing all the time (visibility of controls depending on loaded data)

Any sugestions are welcome

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what the question is? I can see what could be questions, but there are no question marks to distinguish the core question here.

Answer (score 2):

Being at the design phase makes this much easier to suggest patterns and practices, your *question* isn't very clear, so I'll address each point you have made.

> I have to control the view by code because I have to enable, disable or hide elements depending on the user permission. Additionally in a TreeView I have to control the ContextMenu of the TreeViewItems depending of the Item-Type (internal logic) and the dependency of the user permission.

This sounds pretty straightforward, using the MVVM design pattern in this scenario would most probably require an `IValueConverter` to convert a view model `Boolean` property to a view-friendly `Visibility` value. [This](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/) explains how you can achieve that.

> The Data to display are loade by stored procedures to datasets (multiple tables).

I would suggest looking into the [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). This, coupled with the MVVM design pattern should suit your requirements nicely.

> What's the experience with MVVM and maintenance (code complexity of MVVM compared with direct code behind) and all the stearing of controls visibility.

The purpose of MVVM isn't to have no code-behind, it's to ensure that code belongs in the *right place*. Code-behind is not a bad thing, it's **view related code**. There is a much more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805330/wpf-controls-should-code-behind-be-avoided-at-all-costs/30805500#30805500).

In your scenario, it's more than likely that you need properties in your view model to indicate whether the user has the authorization to view certain controls, I assume these permissions are held in the database, therefore the properties would need to live in the view model as you can't get to the database from the view. I hope that made some sense.

MVVM is more maintainable than a code-behind solution as your view models are decoupled from the view, therefore if the view changes, the view model does not necessarily need to change too. This is also true for repositories and models.

MVVM paves the way for a more *agile* solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came from a winforms world, and implementing any MVX style pattern seemed like more hassle but after working on WPF, I can say that MVVM is the best way to proceed. The whole mechanism is supported out-of-the-box.

First, the key benefit is that it enables true separation between the 'View' and 'Model'. This meane that if/when your model needs to change, it can without the view needing to and vice-versa.

Second, your 'model' might have all the data required by your 'view' but this data might be required by your 'view' in some other way. For these transformations 'view model' is required, whithout which these changes would be needed with duplication in model.

You can also use a 'viewmodel' to aggregate parts of your model that exist in separate classes/libraries to facilitate a more fluent interface for the 'view' to deal with. It's very unlikely that you'll want to work with data in your code in the same way that a user will want to or will want that data presented to them.

On top of that, you get support for automatic two-way databinding between the 'view' and 'viewmodel'.

I would also recommend the video here:
http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you are describing is nearly a "perfect-fit" for using MVVM. You can control the visibillity depending on the permissions just by using bindings in the view. You will not need to write any code-behind in the view (beside you have to do some specific UI things) because the entire connection between your "data" (models) and the displaying (view) is done in the viewmodel. 
That also enhances the maintainability, you can touch the view without changing the viewmodel and vice versa.
At the beginning it will be a bit overwhelming and you have to create many properties which seems a bit messy.

In a nutshell:

- View: just the form (layout) the user will see (displaying the data)
- ViewModel: the logic which (in a way) "controls" your view and connects it with your data (models)
- Model: your business logic

For example: In the viewmodel you can set the state of a property which indicates if a control element is visible for the user or not and this property is then bound to the view. In the view you do nothing beside binding the property in the XAML code. It's a good way to stay clean.

I hope this was a bit helpful.

EDIT: here is a [quickstart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) and here are some further [information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2012/03/17/10284665.aspx)