# Dragging window in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have custom window in WPF. I want to implement dragging without violeting MVVM pattern. So I have transparent rectangle on the top, with OnMouseDown event, handled in code-behind:

```
    private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            this.DragMove();
    }
```

Simple. But is it good approach?

I have idea to move this code to ViewModel. Call it via Command, like this:

```
    <Rectangle x:Name="DragRectangle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Fill="Transparent">
        <Rectangle.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DragCommand}"/>
        </Rectangle.InputBindings>
    </Rectangle>
```

But then, I need to have "this" (so Window) in ViewModel. I'm not sure if that's possible (and if so, if that's a good practice).

How should I implement dragging custom window so it will not violate MVVM pattern?

Comment: sometimes, you need to do stuff in code behind. Maybe this article helps you a bit: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874425/Drag-and-Drop-in-MVVM-WPF

Comment: Dragging UI elements is a ***ui concern***.  MVVM != no codebehind.

Comment: I agree, this is UI code, and therefore should remain in the code behind. I have gone into detail about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805330/wpf-controls-should-code-behind-be-avoided-at-all-costs/30805500#30805500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this i will highly recommend you to read this two articles:

- **[Dragging Elements in a Canvas:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas)** In this article, Josh Smith, will you explain the basics of how to create you own custom DragCanvas. How Josh explain will you give the necessary knowledge to continue reading the next article.
- **[Dragging Elements in a Canvas:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387977/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas?q=DragCanvas)** This article, is an improving model of Josh DragCanvas. In this case, Igkutikov, simplify the model and improve the usability of this class.

At last, if you want, I will keep here some modification of my DragCanvas that is forked from Igkutikov project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the mode in which the DragCanvas will act
/// if set to NoDragging will act a simple Canvas
/// if set to AllowDragInView Dragging is enabled but no Draging out of Canvas view is allowed,
/// elements will not get out of DragCanvas borders
/// if set to AllowDragOutOfView dragging is enabled and elements may be dragged out of the
/// DragCanvas borders
/// </summary>
public enum DraggingModes
{
    NoDragging,
    AllowDragInView,
    AllowDragOutOfView
}
/// <summary>
/// Defines to the DragCanvas Relative to which edges of it the element may be repositioned
/// </summary>
internal enum ModificationDirection
{
    None                = 0,
    Left                = 1,
    Right               = 2,
    LeftRight           = 3,
    Top                 = 4,
    LeftTop             = 5,
    RightTop            = 6,
    LeftRightTop        = 7,
    Bottom              = 8,
    LeftBottom          = 9,
    RightBottom         = 10,
    LeftRightBottom     = 11,
    TopBottom           = 12,
    LeftTopBottom       = 13,
    RightTopBottom      = 14,
    LeftRightTopBottom  = 15
}

/// <summary>
/// A Canvas which manages dragging of the UIElements it contains.  
/// </summary>
public class DragCanvas : Canvas
{
#region Data

// Keeps track of where the mouse cursor was when a drag operation began.       
private Point m_InitialCursorLocation;

// The offsets from the DragCanvas' edges when the drag operation began.
private double m_OriginalLefOffset;
private double m_OriginalRightOffset;
private double m_OriginalTopOffset;
private double m_OriginalBottomOffset;

// Keeps track of which horizontal and vertical offset should be modified for the drag element.
private ModificationDirection m_ModificationDirection;

// True if a drag operation is underway, else false.
private bool m_IsDragInProgress;

#endregion // Data

#region Properties

/// <summary>
/// Gets/sets whether elements in the DragCanvas should be draggable by the user.
/// The default value is AllowDragInView.
/// </summary>
private DraggingModes m_DraggingMode;
public DraggingModes DraggingMode
{
    get { return m_DraggingMode; }
    set { m_DraggingMode = value; }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty Draggable;

public static bool GetCanBeDragged(UIElement uiElement)
{
    if (uiElement == null)
        return false;

    return (bool)uiElement.GetValue(Draggable);
}

public static void SetCanBeDragged(UIElement uiElement, bool value)
{
    if (uiElement != null)
        uiElement.SetValue(Draggable, value);
}

// Stores a reference to the UIElement currently being dragged by the user.
private UIElement m_DraggedElement;
/// <summary>
/// Returns the UIElement currently being dragged, or null.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Note to inheritors: This property exposes a protected 
/// setter which should be used to modify the drag element.
/// </remarks>
public UIElement DraggedElement
{
    get
    {
        if (m_DraggingMode == DraggingModes.NoDragging)
            return null;
        else
            return this.m_DraggedElement;
    }
    protected set
    {
        if (this.m_DraggedElement != null)
        {
            this.m_DraggedElement.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
        if (m_DraggingMode == DraggingModes.NoDragging)
        {
            this.m_DraggedElement = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (DragCanvas.GetCanBeDragged(value))
            {
                this.m_DraggedElement = value;
                this.m_DraggedElement.CaptureMouse();
            }
            else
                this.m_DraggedElement = null;
        }
    }
}

#endregion Properties // Properties

#region Constructor

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of DragCanvas.  UIElements in
/// the DragCanvas will immediately be draggable by the user.
/// </summary>
public DragCanvas()
{
    m_DraggingMode = DraggingModes.AllowDragInView;
}

static DragCanvas()
{
    Draggable = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CanBeDragged", typeof(bool), typeof(DragCanvas), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
}

#endregion // Constructor

#region Mouse Handlers Overrides

#region OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e); // call the handler of the base first
    m_IsDragInProgress = false;
    m_InitialCursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this); // Cache the mouse cursor location

    //check if the mouse was clicked on the ScrollBar, in which case let the ScrollBar remain its control. 
    if (null != GetParentOfType<ScrollBar>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject)) { return; }

    // Walk up the visual tree from the element that was clicked, 
    // looking for an element that is a direct child of the Canvas
    DraggedElement = FindCanvasChild(e.Source as DependencyObject);
    if (m_DraggedElement == null) { return; }

    m_ModificationDirection = ResolveOffset(Canvas.GetLeft(m_DraggedElement), Canvas.GetRight(m_DraggedElement), Canvas.GetTop(m_DraggedElement), Canvas.GetBottom(m_DraggedElement));

    // Set the Handled flag so that a control being dragged 
    // does not react to the mouse input
    e.Handled = true;

    if (m_ModificationDirection == ModificationDirection.None)
    {
        DraggedElement = null;
        return;
    }
    BringToFront(m_DraggedElement as UIElement);
    m_IsDragInProgress = true;
}

public static T GetParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject current) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parent = current;
    do
    {
        if (parent is Visual)
        {
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        else
        {
            parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        var result = parent as T;

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
    } while (parent != null);

    return null;
}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

#region OnPreviewMouseMove

protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    // If no element is being dragged, there is nothing to do.
    if (m_DraggedElement == null || !m_IsDragInProgress)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Get the position of the mouse cursor, relative to the Canvas.
    Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

    // These values will store the new offsets of the drag element.
    double _HorizontalOffset = Double.NaN;
    double _VerticalOffset = Double.NaN; ;

    #region Calculate Offsets

    Size _DraggedElemenetSize = m_DraggedElement.RenderSize;

    if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Left) != 0)
    {
        _HorizontalOffset = m_OriginalLefOffset + (cursorLocation.X - m_InitialCursorLocation.X);
        if (m_DraggingMode == DraggingModes.AllowDragInView)
        {
            if (_HorizontalOffset < 0)
            {
                _HorizontalOffset = 0;
            }
            else if ((_HorizontalOffset + _DraggedElemenetSize.Width) > this.ActualWidth)
            {
                _HorizontalOffset = this.ActualWidth - _DraggedElemenetSize.Width;
            }
        }
        m_OriginalLefOffset = _HorizontalOffset;
        m_OriginalRightOffset = this.ActualWidth + _DraggedElemenetSize.Width - m_OriginalLefOffset;
    }
    else if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Right) != 0)
    {
        _HorizontalOffset = m_OriginalRightOffset - (cursorLocation.X - m_InitialCursorLocation.X);
        if (m_DraggingMode == DraggingModes.AllowDragInView)
        {
            if (_HorizontalOffset < 0)
            {
                _HorizontalOffset = 0;
            }
            else if ((_HorizontalOffset + _DraggedElemenetSize.Width) > this.ActualWidth)
            {
                _HorizontalOffset = this.ActualWidth - _DraggedElemenetSize.Width;
            }
        }
        m_OriginalRightOffset = _HorizontalOffset;
        m_OriginalLefOffset = this.ActualWidth + _DraggedElemenetSize.Width - m_OriginalRightOffset;
    }

    if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Top) != 0)
    {
        _VerticalOffset = m_OriginalTopOffset + (cursorLocation.Y - m_InitialCursorLocation.Y);
        if (m_DraggingMode == DraggingModes.AllowDragInView)
        {
            if (_VerticalOffset < 0)
            {
                _VerticalOffset = 0;
            }
            else if ((_VerticalOffset + _DraggedElemenetSize.Height) > this.ActualHeight)
            {
                _VerticalOffset = this.ActualHeight - _DraggedElemenetSize.Height;
            }
        }
        m_OriginalTopOffset = _VerticalOffset;
        m_OriginalBottomOffset = this.ActualHeight + _DraggedElemenetSize.Height - m_OriginalTopOffset;
    }
    else if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Bottom) != 0)
    {
        _VerticalOffset = m_OriginalBottomOffset - (cursorLocation.Y - m_InitialCursorLocation.Y);
        if (m_DraggingMode == DraggingModes.AllowDragInView)
        {
            if (_VerticalOffset < 0)
            {
                _VerticalOffset = 0;
            }
            else if ((_VerticalOffset + _DraggedElemenetSize.Height) > this.ActualHeight)
            {
                _VerticalOffset = this.ActualHeight - _DraggedElemenetSize.Height;
            }
        }
        m_OriginalBottomOffset = _VerticalOffset;
        m_OriginalTopOffset = this.ActualHeight + _DraggedElemenetSize.Height - m_OriginalBottomOffset;
    }

    m_InitialCursorLocation = cursorLocation;

    #endregion // Calculate Offsets

    #region Move Drag Element

    if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Left) != 0)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(m_DraggedElement, _HorizontalOffset);
    }
    else if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Right) != 0)
    {
        Canvas.SetRight(m_DraggedElement, _HorizontalOffset);
    }
    if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Top) != 0)
    {
        Canvas.SetTop(m_DraggedElement, _VerticalOffset);
    }
    else if ((m_ModificationDirection & ModificationDirection.Bottom) != 0)
    {
        Canvas.SetBottom(m_DraggedElement, _VerticalOffset);
    }

    #endregion // Move Drag Element
}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseMove

#region OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp

protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

    // Reset the field whether the left or right mouse button was 
    // released, in case a context menu was opened on the drag element.
    m_IsDragInProgress = false;
    DraggedElement = null;
}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp

#region OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown

protected override void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown(e);


}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseRightButtonDown

#region OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp

protected override void OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp(e);
}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseRightButtonUp

#endregion Mouse Handlers Overrides

#region Public Methods

/// <summary>
/// Assigns the element a z-index which will ensure that 
/// it is in front of every other element in the Canvas.
/// The z-index of every element whose z-index is between 
/// the element's old and new z-index will have its z-index 
/// decremented by one.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">
/// The element to be sent to the front of the z-order.
/// </param>
public void BringToFront(UIElement element)
{
    UpdateZOrder(element, true);
}

/// <summary>
/// Assigns the element a z-index which will ensure that 
/// it is behind every other element in the Canvas.
/// The z-index of every element whose z-index is between 
/// the element's old and new z-index will have its z-index 
/// incremented by one.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">
/// The element to be sent to the back of the z-order.
/// </param>
public void SendToBack(UIElement element)
{
    UpdateZOrder(element, false);
}

#endregion // Public Methods

#region Private Helper Methods

    #region UpdateZOrder

/// <summary>
/// Helper method used by the BringToFront and SendToBack methods.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">
/// The element to bring to the front or send to the back.
/// </param>
/// <param name="bringToFront">
/// Pass true if calling from BringToFront, else false.
/// </param>
private void UpdateZOrder(UIElement element, bool bringToFront)
{
        #region Safety Check

    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

    if (!base.Children.Contains(element))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be a child element of the Canvas.", "element");

        #endregion // Safety Check

        #region Calculate Z-Indexes And Offset

    // Determine the Z-Index for the target UIElement.
    int elementNewZIndex = -1;
    if (bringToFront)
    {
        foreach (UIElement elem in base.Children)
        {
            if (elem.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                ++elementNewZIndex;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        elementNewZIndex = 0;
    }

    // Determine if the other UIElements' Z-Index 
    // should be raised or lowered by one. 
    int offset = (elementNewZIndex == 0) ? +1 : -1;

    int elementCurrentZIndex = Canvas.GetZIndex(element);

        #endregion // Calculate Z-Indici And Offset

        #region Update Z-Indexes

    // Update the Z-Index of every UIElement in the Canvas.
    foreach (UIElement childElement in base.Children)
    {
        if (childElement == element)
        {
            Canvas.SetZIndex(element, elementNewZIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            int zIndex = Canvas.GetZIndex(childElement);

            // Only modify the z-index of an element if it is  
            // in between the target element's old and new z-index.
            if (bringToFront && elementCurrentZIndex < zIndex || !bringToFront && zIndex < elementCurrentZIndex)
            {
                Canvas.SetZIndex(childElement, zIndex + offset);
            }
        }
    }
        #endregion // Update Z-Indexes
}

    #endregion // UpdateZOrder

    #region ResolveOffset

/// <summary>
/// Determines one component of a UIElement's location 
/// within a Canvas (horizontal or vertical offset)
/// and according to it reletive to which sides it may be relocated
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Left">
/// The value of an offset relative to a Left side of the Canvas
/// </param>
/// <param name="Right">
/// The value of the offset relative to the Right side of the Canvas
/// </param>
/// <param name="Top">
/// The value of an offset relative to a Top side of the Canvas
/// </param>
/// <param name="Bottom">
/// The value of the offset relative to the Bottom side of the Canvas
/// </param>
private ModificationDirection ResolveOffset(double Left, double Right, double Top, double Bottom)
{
    // If the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Right attached properties 
    // are specified for an element, the 'Left' value is honored.
    // The 'Top' value is honored if both Canvas.Top and 
    // Canvas.Bottom are set on the same element.  If one 
    // of those attached properties is not set on an element, 
    // the default value is Double.NaN.
    m_OriginalLefOffset = Left;
    m_OriginalRightOffset = Right;
    m_OriginalTopOffset = Top;
    m_OriginalBottomOffset = Bottom;
    ModificationDirection result = ModificationDirection.None;
    if (!Double.IsNaN(m_OriginalLefOffset))
    {
        result |= ModificationDirection.Left;
    }
    if (!Double.IsNaN(m_OriginalRightOffset))
    {
        result |= ModificationDirection.Right;
    }
    if (!Double.IsNaN(m_OriginalTopOffset))
    {
        result |= ModificationDirection.Top;
    }
    if (!Double.IsNaN(m_OriginalBottomOffset))
    {
        result |= ModificationDirection.Bottom;
    }
    return result;
}

    #endregion // ResolveOffset

    #region FindCanvasChild

/// <summary>
/// Walks up the visual tree starting with the specified DependencyObject, 
/// looking for a UIElement which is a child of the Canvas.  If a suitable 
/// element is not found, null is returned.  If the 'depObj' object is a 
/// UIElement in the Canvas's Children collection, it will be returned.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="depObj">
/// A DependencyObject from which the search begins.
/// </param>
private UIElement FindCanvasChild(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    while (depObj != null)
    {
        // If the current object is a UIElement which is a child of the
        // Canvas, exit the loop and return it.
        UIElement elem = depObj as UIElement;
        if (elem != null && base.Children.Contains(elem))
        {
            break;
        }

        // VisualTreeHelper works with objects of type Visual or Visual3D.
        // If the current object is not derived from Visual or Visual3D,
        // then use the LogicalTreeHelper to find the parent element.
        if (depObj is Visual || depObj is Visual3D)
        {
            depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
        }
        else
        {
            depObj = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
        }
    }
    return depObj as UIElement;
}

    #endregion // FindCanvasChild

#endregion 
}
```