# Unable to get position in the canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a user control that has an ellipse. I have added the user control to canvas. I try this code to get coordinates of the ellipse relative to canvas:

```
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
```

Since the ellipse, I think, not a direct member of the canvas I get NaN. I have searched and found something like this:

```
Point relativePoint = ellipse.TransformToAncestor(canvas).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

But later I have awaired that the code just below does not provide actual coordinate, gives me something different. How can I get actual coordinates?

Comment: Canvas.GetLeft is available if you set Canvas.Left on a DependencyObject. You won't be able to get it if you don't set it, that's why you  get NaN. You can get the relative position to the canvas using the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1923775/4049478)

Comment: You should never do this. Use MVVM.

Answer (score -3):

Just don't do it. Read a couple of articles on MVVM and you will never need to ask something like this

You need to bind your control to a VM.

```
public class ControlVM
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" >
    ... specify Canvas as the items panel ...
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

if you do it like this, you will never need to ask the control for it's coordinates, but the object representing it.

Comment: His problem is about the View layer, nothing to do with MVVM.

Comment: You are wrong. He should bind object to control's x and y position. If he even tries, to play with absolute positions he will most of the time recieve NaN as a value. MVVM and WPF are about solving the DPI issues, and for that reason shoulnd you never work with absolute positions.

Comment: In most cases, when someone asks a question like this it is not a problem to solve but an issue he comes across, because he is wrong in the first place. Most of the time it is about positioning controls, because he does not understand how to place controls inside of panels and grids

Comment: Nothing allows you to assume he has a bad design and that he needs a ViewModel layer. What we know: He wants to get the position of an Ellipse relative to a Canvas. This kind of interaction resides exclusively in the View layer and MVVM has nothing to do with it until he tells something that allows us to think about bad design

Comment: Just leaving [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30805500/4049478) in hope you get some humility. Take a look at any Control at referencesource (microsoft framework source) and see if they don't use code-behind. Code-behind is ok as long as it uses UI logic, no data.

Comment: Sorry guys to keep you busy but the second code I wrote in my question is working. It was something else that is the problem, I understood. I will use that since I have no consideration about the performance. Thanks everyone who answer